# I know it & I know that

Tags: word-choice

John) Hey, did you know George's getting married?

Paul)

A: Wow, I didn't know that.

B: Wow, I didn't know it.

I wonder if A and B are both equally acceptable or one of them could be jarring.  Thank you.

Comment: Only A is acceptable. B would definitely be seen as jarring.

Comment: But Paul might say "Wow, I _didn't_ know" (_it_ or _that_ being implied).

Comment: Could you please tell me when "it" becomes jarring?  I don't know what makes the difference.

Comment: We would use _it_ to say that we know a _thing or place_, but not that we have heard a piece of news or a fact. "I've just finished reading that book about China by Author X." "Yes, I know it - it's called Y, isn't it?"