# What's the difference between "I know it." and "I know that"?

Tags: word-choice

[I know it & I know that](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/302358/i-know-it-i-know-that)

Here in this question, I got an answer that you say "it" to refer to a thing while you say "that" to refer to a fact.

However, I often hear people say "I knew it!" when they find out their expectation is correct.  Why isn't it "I knew that!" though it refers to a fact?

I also often hear them say "I don't believe it" instead of "I don't believe that" when they don't want to believe a fact.  Why is that?

Is it really true that you say "it" to refer to a thing and "that" to refer to a fact?

Comment: Thank you for linking to the previous question. However, you didn't get an actual answer to it, only responses in comments. [This help page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) provides advice about what to do in such a situation. (Basically, you shouldn't create a new question to follow up on a previous one unless they are really asking distinct things.) I think that this question may get closed as a duplicate, since it's asking very similar questions.

Comment: OK, it seems I was the person who made that comment. It was meant to refer to the sentence that the question was about, not to be a general rule. _That_ usually refers to something that has just been mentioned, so if someone has just told you something you already know, you would say "I know that" - but if something happens as expected without it having been spoken of, you might well say "I knew it!"